# How to convert large list of dictionary to dataframe/matrix

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of dictionaries which has about 5 million lines.
The list looks like this:

```
[{"a":100, "b":50},{"c":2,"a":10}]
```

What I want is a dataframe or matrix like this:

```
a     b    c    
100  50   0    
10    0   2
```

Then I will feed it into a cluster algorithm.

The `pd.DataFrame(list)` works fine when the list is not large. But the list 
I got can not fit into memory.

I tried to turn the list into spase matrix, but still, memory error accured when doing kmeans.

So is there a way to create a huge matrix from the list, for example write to hard drive line by line? In this case, I can read this huge matrix line by line from hard drive, and then doing kmeans.

Thanks a lot

Comment: You were able to successfully construct a sparse matrix? The memory error happened when you tried to run k-means?

Answer (score 0):

Should you not use [`df.from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) ?

To feed into a cluster algorithm you could convert the resulting numeric columns into a numpy array:

```
# convert the numeric cols into a two-dimensional numpy array
# will cast the columns into a numpy array in the form of Tuples    
numpy_array = df.as_matrix(columns = ['col_one', 'col_two'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If the list doesn't fit in memory, you could loop through your list chunk by chunk (full disclosure: I don't know how slow/fast this solution is):

```
import pandas as pd
tmp = []
chunksize = 100
df = pd.DataFrame()
for j, item in enumerate(mylist):
    tmp.append(item)
    if j % chunksize == chunksize-1:
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(tmp)
        df = pd.concat([df, df2], ignore_index=True)
        tmp = []
df2 = pd.DataFrame(tmp)
df = pd.concat([df, df2], ignore_index=True)
```